# Resize UITabBar button in StoryBoard

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa, ios6

I am trying to get the button sizes on UITabBar which I have set as MainViewController however, I want to resize the button with the images I got, it seams to be bit wider. Can this be done from storyboard portal or it has to be done from XCode, and if so how can it be done?

Thanks.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: This question does not make sense.

Comment: So what I have tried so far is a mixmatch of the contents in iOS using story board and custom image on tab bar item. Since the custom tab bar item is just an image in the middle, I am presenting it on the main view controller. This still lets me have the flexibility of having storyboard intact.

Comment: Just resize your image to the size you want, and set it by accessing self.tabBarItem.image in the view controller you want it to represent.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know it's not possible using any standard functions in UITabBar to resize the UITabBarItem.

But here's some interesting sites that may help you with custom solutions:

- [How does the Twitter iPhone App implement a custom tab bar?](http://idevrecipes.com/2011/01/04/how-does-the-twitter-iphone-app-implement-a-custom-tab-bar/) (idevrecipes)
- [Custom tabBar](https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/CustomTabBar) (gihub)
- [The iPhone Tab Bar](http://www.significantpixels.com/2011/04/04/the-iphone-tab-bar/) (significantpixels)

hope this will help you,

Cheers!